# Need to make Sum IIF query in linq vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am new with the linq and i need to do this query with linq in vb.net from a data table

Every column are setted to VAR CHAR if its useful for the query:

```
SELECT Sum(IIf([ColumnNameToCountValues] IN 
    ('value1','value2','value3') 
     And [EmployeId] Like '[IDvalue]' 
     And [PROJECT] LIKE '[ProjectName]',1,0)) 
    AS Total FROM [DatatableName];
```

This query should return an integer.

Comment: [This might be a good start for you](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx).

Comment: I dont see a question here.

Answer (score 0):

where are your error and what are your question also what have you tried? From what you have said `"This query should return an integer."` May be your output got error, isn't it?
So, why not just change your database column data type to `INT`

Comment: i need to count the number of time the value1 , the value2 and the value3 are repeated in the column X .. the values are not integer its like DO , DE ,PM ... for now i do it with a query and executescalar...